# Changing colors from clusters for each class

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have a scatter plot where i am plotting 14 clusters, but each 2 clusters belong to the same class, they are plotted in 14 different colors, but i need only 2 colors. Therefore i would have just 2 different classes for the 14 clusters as they would be grouped in pairs. My clusters are enumerated from A(1) to N(14) in my dataframe. What i want to do is identify each cluster by their color for instance every odd gets blue color, every even gets red color. Or if you're going by letters: A gets blue, B gets red, C gets blue, D gets red, E gets blue and etc.

[Link for the Data Frame](http://www.mediafire.com/file/7ngfzti158bdrqc/lda_values/file)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

y = [0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
  0,  0,  0,  0, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,
  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,
  1,  1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,
  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,
  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,
  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,
  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,
  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,
  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,
  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,
  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,
  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,
  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,
  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,
  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,
  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,
  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,
  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,
  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9, 10, 10, 10, 10,
 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10,
 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11,
 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11,
 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11,
 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12,
 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12,
 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13,
 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13,
 13, 13, 13, 13]
X_lda = pd.read_pickle('lda_values')
X_lda = np.asarray(X_lda)


plt.xlabel('1-eigenvector')
plt.ylabel('2-eigenvector')
plt.scatter(
    X_lda[:,0],
    X_lda[:,1],
    c=y,
    cmap='rainbow',
    alpha=0.7,
    edgecolors='w'
)
```

This is the minimal reproducible example i could get from a large code with large data.

What i am doing is im setting a different color for a different class in y, the data in X_lda, where first 50 rows are blue, from 50 to 100 is red, 101-150 blue, 151-200 red. and forth.

This is the actual plot:

[image]

This is more or less what i am trying to achieve.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the example below to plot the data. Suppose there are five clusters as 0,1,2,3,4 and you want to use **blue color** for samples in **clusters 0,2,4** and **red color** for samples in **clusters 1,3**.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

X_lda=np.array([[1,2],[1,1],[3,3],[4,4],[2,4],[3,5],[3,4],[3,2]]) # suppose you want to plot X

y=[0,1,1,1,2,3,4,4] # the cluster of each sample in X_lda 

color=['b','r'] # You want to use blue for samples in clusters 0,2,4 and red color for samples in clusters 1,3 
X_lda_colors=  [ color[i] for i in list(np.array(y)%2) ] # get the color for each sample in X_lda

plt.xlabel('1-eigenvector')
plt.ylabel('2-eigenvector')
plt.scatter(
    X_lda[:,0],
    X_lda[:,1],
    c=X_lda_colors,
    cmap='rainbow',
    alpha=0.7,
    edgecolors='w'
)
plt.show()
```